# How to alter html after html on document.ready javascript

Tags: javascript, html, document

I need to alter html (hide or show element) after on document ready, however, simply doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#element').hide();
});
```

causes the document.ready to be called recurcively... should i simply use a boolean called=true, and then only call element.hide() if alled==false? or is there a better way to do this? thanks...

Comment: what is the use case you are looking for? Because if you want something hidden, you can just hide it via CSS using `display : none;`

Comment: How is it being called recursively?

Comment: are you sure it's called recursively ? I see really no way how that can happen in your code. everything inside `.ready()` will be executed when element (body) is ready .. once, if it's called once

Comment: it cannot possibly be called recursively unless you are developing your own browser... **something else on the site is triggering the code**...

Comment: How do you wantto alter(show and hide) the html. There must be some trigger. Can you explain your problem a bit more

Comment: Are you talking about **toggle** ?

Comment: You are doing the right thing, nothing should be able to trigger document ready over and over again..  unless you have a piece of code that does it ..

Comment: What is happening that I think is troubling you is that the element is instantly hidden upon the document being ready not that it's being called recursively. If you want to delay the hiding effect `setTimeout()` can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just hide the element, you can do it by only css i.e. `#element: display: none;`

If you want to show/hide the particular item on clicking the same, you can use `.toggle(speed,easing,callback)` method, like:
`$('#element').toggle()`;

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is to hide the `element` after a certain time and not hiding it as the page loads the you can use the jQuery `setTimeout` like this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#element").hide()
}, 3000);
```

This will hide the `element` 3 seconds after the page loads